# What happens if a Teleportation Circle destinations moves?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, teleportation

So I want to make a Howl's Moving Castle home base, but I want to be able to have visitors teleport in from a little cottage. My DM and I are wondering if a [Teleportation Circle](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleportationCircle.htm) that was made permanent could hit a moving target. The description says that a circle has a set destination, but it doesn't have anything on the destination moving.

Tl:Dr Can a Teleport Circle have a destination that is in motion/ not where it used to be?

Comment: Isn't the world constantly moving? I get what you are saying though, I would imagine it would have to be in relation to something. Like the center of a specific room.

Comment: Unfortunatly that argument would invalidate any set destination limitation, since you could relate its position to a piece of equipment you are carrying. Edit: The argument might still be valid, but it could cause problems with other spells.

Comment: As an alternative solution, you could go with something along the lines of a pair of unusually large ring gates. Their effects are already well-defined, and the only reason they wouldn't work as-is for your situation is that they are too small for a Medium creature to fit through (they do exactly what you want for creatures smaller than that). All you'd need a DM ruling for is on whether they can be made that large, and how much extra they would cost at that size. That's still a house rule, but it's a much more minor one than nailing down the particulars of what constitutes a "spot".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Maybe

The 9th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*teleportation circle*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleportationCircle.htm) [conj] (*PH* 293) says that

> You create a circle on the floor or other horizontal surface that teleports, as *greater teleport*, any creature who stands on it to a designated spot.

But it's the DM's decision both how one goes about *designating* and what, exactly, is a *spot*. Here are some choices:

1. **Appearance:** Designate a spot by describing a location. The greater, more unique, and specific the details, the more unlikely a false destination.
2. **Coordinates:** Designate a spot by assigning it a latitude and longitude. Thus spots that move can't be designated.
3. **Crosshairs:** Designate a spot by selecting a crosshairs; spots the caster's never seen can still be designated. Thus only locations large enough to have their own maps (e.g. a ship, a flying fortress) will have spots that can be designated.
4. **Name:** Designate a spot by using its name, and employing the spell *teleportation circle* to travel to the named spot takes the creature to the location. (I suggest the location's most commonly used entrance.)
5. **Relative Location:** Designate the spot by its relationship to something else (e.g. creatures, landmarks, objects, terrain features).

Also keep in mind that while the caster can't arrive off target using the 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*greater teleport*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleportGreater.htm) (*PH* 293) (hence neither with the spell *teleportation circle*), he must still roll on the chart for the 5th-level spell [*teleport*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleport.htm) [conj] (*PH* 292-3) when the effect's used, and the possibility of a false destination or outright failure still exists if using the spell *teleportation circle* to teleport blind. (Despite the spell *teleportation circle* failing if its caster lacks familiarity with the destination, how one can become *just* familiar (rather than *very familiar* as described in the spell *teleport*) with a destination is never made clear.)

Comment: I can imagine justifying your third point in-setting by making the requirement "Anything big enough to have its own gravitational field" and using Spelljammer gravity as a guide.

Comment: @GMJoe #3 is our house rule for spell areas moving (although not teleportation). *An aside:* Spell areas on a ship forced  us to address if the universe is made of immutable 5-ft. squares that impose themselves onto materials (making area effects immovable) or if things have their unique sets of 5-ft. squares that can overlap with other things' 5-ft. squares (making effects moveable). We agreed on the latter, although the former is more elegant.