# Can You Plane Shift to a Plane You Never Visited?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I was wondering if you can *[plane shift](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/plane-shift)* to a plane you never visited since you seem to need to specify a destination?

Comment: [Related.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/34269/8610) Although for *D&D 3.5*, *Pathfinder* raises similar questions. Further, consider defining in the campaign's house rules the term *destination*, perhaps as in this [answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/41393/8610).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## You don't need to visit a plane to go there.

The only thing that the description of *plane shift* says about where you arrive is:

> you appear 5 to 500 miles (5d%) from your intended destination

Compare this with *[teleport](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleport)*, which says:

> You must have some clear idea of the location and layout of the destination.

*Teleport* also has a bunch of other information about targeting a location, which says (among other things) that you need to at least see a place to *teleport* there.  Since some transport magic specifically says that you need to see a place to go there, it implies that spells that don't say you need to see a place to go there, don't have that requirement.

The fact that *plane shift* says that you arrive near your destination, you *do* need to have a destination.  However, this can be defined any way that your DM considers precise enough to count as a 'location'.  For example, you could say that you wanted to go to a particular githyanki outpost in the Astral Plane, or a particular efreet keep on the Plane of Fire that you've heard of.  As long as you can name a place, you can *plane shift* there.

Comment: Is it worth saying something about tuning forks here? (I upvoted, but the tuning fork is the main way DMs prevent players from *plane shift*-ing anywhere in the multiverse.)

Comment: Is it?  That's odd, I've never seen it ruled that way.  The 'tuning fork' doesn't have a gold cost, and "Assume that focus components of negligible cost are in your spell component pouch."  There is similar wording on the 3.5 SRD.  I've never played in a game where the 'tuning fork' was a thing that mattered.

Comment: Huh. It's not on the SRD, but the 3.5 PHB has: "Forked rods keyed to certain planes or dimensions may be difficult to come by, as decided by the GM." I think the primary purpose is to make sure that you can't get into Mordenkainen's personal demiplane and grab all his stuff.

Comment: Minor nitpicking perhaps, but don't you automatically visit a plane when you go there? Unless you meant "You don't have to have visited a plane before to go there"?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer The spell *plane shift* in *Pathfinder* requires a forked rod as its focus, regardless of the spell's source. (Check the spell's Components entry.)

Answer (score 6):

As a component of the spell **Plane Shift** it is required that you have *a forked metal rod attuned to the plane of travel*.

As long as that requirement is met you can travel to any plane - whether or not you've visited it previously.